# Capture points in array from free hand drawing in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Lets say I am displaying an image in Matlab, and then want to draw a freehand contour/shape overlaying on the image. And then capture the points on the contour in an array.

Is it possible within Matlab? If so, please suggest how can I achieve that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is the builtin [ginput](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/ginput.html) function, but it requires you to click points so it isn't really freehand.

[This](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4170-trace-the-position-of-cursor-without-click) user made function might do what you want though.

Comment: Thanks for the response, now I have more than one way to do the same job.

Answer (score 2):

The `imfreehand` function in the image processing toolbox does what you're looking for:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imfreehand.html

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Yesterday was my first day with image processing tool box. I should have spent time on reading documents/examples :).